# added an accepted domain to exchange server, but cannot choose it as a logon domain when creating email addresses?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

i'm currently running exchange 2010 and i recently acquired a new domain name because i'd like to be able to accept emails using the new domain name.  all the dns stuff is set up and i've added the domain to the list of accepted domains in hub transport.  however, when i go to create new email addresses, the new domain name is not in the drop down list of logon domains.  how do i get it there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Shane has mentioned, it's a bit different. I do think it's generally a good idea to have UPNs match up to email addresses though as it makes users' lives easier (I fight for the users). So if you'd like to do that, add it as a UPN suffix for the forrest. There is a Microsoft KB article available here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243629

Here's a basic recap of the KB article:

1. Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts.
2. Right-click Active Directory Domains and Trusts in the Tree window pane, and then click Properties.
3. On the UPN Suffixes tab, type the new UPN suffix that you would like to add to the forrest.
4. Click Add, and then click OK

Once that's done, you may add user accounts with the UPN suffix you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a user, not an email address.  A logon domain is an Active Directory domain, which doesn't necessarily correlate in any way with a user's email address or Exchange's authoritative domains list.

Create the account in the domain that makes sense, then get the user a primary SMTP address and recipient policy that fit with the account's needs.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I spent the whole weekend trying to work this out, but it’s just that simple, your instructions @Jason Berg were so simple, so easy and best of all IT WORKS, thank so much, reading your answer has just made my week.

I realize that this doesnt add a public email domain to a user, it just allows that when that other stuff has been configured in Exchange server with the new or other domain name, this is how the user can access their new email using their own domain instead of "myname@mydomain.local" where it becomes and issue if you have users with same username on differnet domains like dave@abc.com and dave@def.com, they cant both sign in with dave@mydomain.local.

I love it and hate it when stuff is so simple yet so hard to find out how to do it, it’s the best feeling when you find an answer that works and isn’t overly complicated :)